# Ubuntu ISO download file from mirror hash checksum is not the same as original

Tags: system-installation, iso

This is my first post. I downloaded the ISO file from the Ubuntu website which automatically redirects to some of its mirrors and I performed a checksum.

The hashes were not equal to those expressed on http://releases.ubuntu.com/, I re-downloaded the file from the same mirror again just to be sure It's not because of corrupted downloading, but again the hash was not matching.

So I found the original source on ubuntu and downloaded file and the hashes were matching this time. The file sizes were exactly the same.

You can see the results in the attachment. The left one is from the mirror and the right one is the file from the original source.

[image]

Mirror:
https://ubuntu.osuosl.org/releases/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: I'm glad that you checked the download with a checksum from the official Ubuntu web site. We recommend that you download Ubuntu or use torrent files from the official websites in order to avoid problems.

Comment: Suggest you contact the sysadmins info@osuosl.org at that mirror site https://osuosl.org/services/hosting/ & let them know of the corrupted file. They're the folks who have to fix it.

Comment: What is the difference in file sizes? You better use https://releases.ubuntu.com (notice S in https) as this makes harder to perform MitM attacks.

Comment: I contacted the mirror website support@osuosl.org and they kindly checked and verified checksum on their servers